# Do you know how to compare two PDF and set comment?

Tags: pdf, automation, publishing, file-comparison

I know similiar questions have been asked here, but this one is different!

I have to compare two PDFs of a book. One is my original and the second is the pre-print version from the publisher.
The two versions are with regard to the content similar, only the formate is different.

The problem is, that the publisher removed all my overturns which are tremendously important.

Thus, I have to set a comment on or mark the places where the overturns where removed so that the editor corrects them.

Has anybody an idea how I could automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about automating but [DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) can be used to compare to PDF files and show the differences.

Comment: The question asks about automating the process of comparing PDFs and setting comments where differences are found.